# c# updating table using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to update my table with this LINQ query

```
public void updateProduct(
    int selectedIDToUpdate, 
    string prodNAMEToUp, 
    double prodPriceToUp, 
    string prodTYPEToUp, 
    int prodMANUToUp, 
    int prodCODEToUp)
{
     DataClassesLINQEPOSDataContext dcld = new DataClassesLINQEPOSDataContext();
     TBLPRODUCT tblprod = (from prod in dcld.TBLPRODUCTs
                           where prod.product_id == selectedIDToUpdate
                           select prod).First();
     tblprod.product_name = prodNAMEToUp;
     tblprod.product_price = prodPriceToUp;
     tblprod.product_type = prodTYPEToUp;
     tblprod.product_manufacturer = prodMANUToUp;
     tblprod.product_code = prodCODEToUp;
     dcld.SubmitChanges();
}
```

and then when I start to run the program I have this error

"InvalidCastException was unhandled"
"Specified cast is not valid."

Sorry I cant post image because I dont have enough reputation "points" :(

this is the control to pass the parameter on my class.

```
private void btnSaveToUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtNameToUpdate.Text != "" || 
        txtPriceToUpdate.Text != "" || 
        txtTypeToUpdate.Text != "" || 
        txtCodeToUpdate.Text != "")
        {
            Connection_Products update = new Connection_Products();
            int selctedID = selectedIDToUpdate;
            string prodNAMEToUp = txtNameToUpdate.Text;
            double prodPriceToUp = double.Parse(txtPriceToUpdate.Text);
            string prodTYPEToUp = txtTypeToUpdate.Text;
            int prodMANUToUp = Convert.ToInt32(cmbManufacturerToUpdate.SelectedValue);
            int prodCODEToUp = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodeToUpdate.Text);
            update.updateProduct(selctedID, prodNAMEToUp, prodPriceToUp, 
            prodTYPEToUp, prodMANUToUp, prodCODEToUp);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: please post db structure as well

Comment: i cant post image Sir Amit Agrawal.

Comment: upload image on http://imageshack.us/ and post the link

Comment: When you debug it at what point in this method does it throw the exception?

Comment: Or just type out what the data types of the different columns are. You dont need an image for this.

Comment: "Specified cast is not valid." means that you do invalid type convert,, please check you DB and values which you use to update

Comment: I'm surprised no one has asked for the full exception to be posted. Can you post the full exception including at least the top few lines of the stack trace? You can copy it to the clipboard as text, there is no reason to post an image.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have some datatype mismatch between the values that you are trying to store and the data types of the columns in the database. This would be in one of the numeric columns.

If the `prodPriceToUp` column uses the `money` data type, this maps to a `decimal` type in Linq2Sql. You are trying to cast the `double` for the input parameter to decimal, which may be causing this issue. Try converting `prodPriceToUp` to a `decimal` before saving it.

Comment: i used money datatype for "prodPriceToUp"... and double for my parameter.

Comment: I already fixed the problem, maybe because of data type from database and DBML connection. I just deleted my DBML and create another one and now it's working.

Comment: If you found that this answer led you to solve your problem, please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing something in type mapping between `updateProduct` params and properties in `tblprod`. Please check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx) you are using correct types

Answer (score 0):

This is because one of the following is trying to cast into an invalid type:

```
 tblprod.product_name = prodNAMEToUp;
 tblprod.product_price = prodPriceToUp;
 tblprod.product_type = prodTYPEToUp;
 tblprod.product_manufacturer = prodMANUToUp;
 tblprod.product_code = prodCODEToUp;
```

Check for each of the these that the type of the left side is the same as the type of the right side. for example ensure that "tblprod.product_name" is a string property as you are trying to save a string to that property.

It is also possible that in your LINQ query, the where clause may have this problem, ensure that "prod.product_id" is an integer and not something else like a long or a short.

if these are all ok and you are still getting the exception then you will need to tell use what line is throwing the exception, and give use the details of the structure of tblprod;

Comment: I tried to comment out that part of codes then I have same error result.

Comment: on a sidenote, you are leaving yourself open to exceptions being thrown when you read in and parse a double from txtpricetoupdate.txt. if the user inputs a non parseable value such as "testvalue" this will fail. You should put in validation such as:

Comment: Sorry comment broke!  double.tryparse(txtpricetoupdate.txt, out value);